# Can I add my own type conversion operators to be able to convert C++ object to objective C?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have C++ vector of integers which I need to turn into an objective C NSArray. One way to do is to loop over all the elements, take each int and copy to NSArray, this can be done with a function but is there a way to write an operator/constructor for NSArray which accepts std::vector as a parameter and makes an Array, in other words am I allowed to extend the NSArray class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a category on NSArray like:

NSArray+vector.h:

```
#include <vector>

@interface NSArray (vector)

-(id)initWithVector:(std::vector<int>)v1;

@end
```

NSArray+vector.m:

```
#import "NSArray+vector.h"

@implementation NSArray (vector)

-(id)initWithVector:(std::vector<int>)v1{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i =0; i < v1.size(); i++){
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:v1.at(i)]];
    }
    return [array copy];
}

@end
```

I didn't debugged it but it should work.